# How to Enable only month and year in Movilizer Calendar screen?

Tags: c#, movilizer

How can we select only month and Year(I don't want to select date) in Movilizer Calendar screen.

Here i want to select only month and year from calendar screen.

Please let me know if any information.

Thanks,
Krish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. If you want to choose a date and after that get only the month and year, it is possible, for example using this function:

```
$global:stringDatetimeToArray = function(datetime)
{
    array['year']   =  substring(datetime, 0, 4);
    array['month']  =  substring(datetime, 5, 7);
                
    return array;
};
```

But if you point is to show a calendar with only year and month I think, as far as I know and didn't read similar thing in confluence, is not possible.
My recommendation is to put a screen item screen or similar and implement maybe two dropdown answers to represent years and months